# BottomNavigation Pages is not reloading everytime when I tap

Tags: flutter, flutter-bottomnavigation

I have a MainPage with bottomnavigation bar with bottomnavigation items. I want to call APIs of bottomnavigation item pages whenever i tap on it i.e I want to reload page everytime I vist the page.

But in my case its not reloading everytime but at once when mainpage called all api of bottomnavigation items page APIs are called attime.

MainPage

```
class MainPage extends StatefulWidget{
  @override
  _MainPageState createState() => new _MainPageState();
}

class _MainPageState extends State<MainPage>{
  ListQueue<int> _navigationQueue = ListQueue();
  int _selectedIndex = 0;
  int counter = Constant.CART_COUNT;

  List<GlobalKey<NavigatorState>> _navigatorKeys = [
    GlobalKey<NavigatorState>(),
    GlobalKey<NavigatorState>(),
    GlobalKey<NavigatorState>(),
    GlobalKey<NavigatorState>()
  ];
  Future<void> secureScreen() async {
    await FlutterWindowManager.addFlags(FlutterWindowManager.FLAG_SECURE);
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    secureScreen();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return WillPopScope(

      onWillPop: () async {
        if (_navigationQueue.isEmpty) return true;
        setState(() {
          _navigationQueue.removeLast();
          int position = _navigationQueue.isEmpty ? 0 : _navigationQueue.last;
          _selectedIndex = position;
        });
        return false;
      },
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
          type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
          currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
          selectedItemColor: Colors.blueAccent,
          showSelectedLabels: true,
          showUnselectedLabels: false,
          items: [
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(
                FontAwesome.home,
                color: Colors.grey,
              ),
              label: 'Home',
              activeIcon: Icon(
                FontAwesome.home,
                color: Colors.blueAccent,
              ),
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(
                FontAwesome.product_hunt,
                color: Colors.grey,
              ),
              label: 'Products',
              activeIcon: Icon(
                FontAwesome.product_hunt,
                color: Colors.blueAccent,
              ),
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(
                FontAwesome.users,
                color: Colors.grey,
              ),
              label: 'Customers',
              activeIcon: Icon(
                FontAwesome.users,
                color: Colors.blueAccent,
              ),
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(
                FontAwesome.search_plus,
                color: Colors.grey,
              ),
              label: 'Order Details',
              activeIcon: Icon(
                FontAwesome.users,
                color: Colors.blueAccent,
              ),
            ),
          ],
          onTap: (index) {
            if(_selectedIndex == _selectedIndex){
              _navigationQueue.removeWhere((element) => element == index);
              _navigationQueue.addLast(index);
              setState(() {
                this._selectedIndex = index;
              });
            }
          },
        ),
        body: Stack(
          children: [
            _buildOffstageNavigator(0),
            _buildOffstageNavigator(1),
            _buildOffstageNavigator(2),
            _buildOffstageNavigator(3)
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }


  Map<String, WidgetBuilder> _routeBuilders(BuildContext context, int index) {
    return {
      '/': (context) {
        return [
          HomePage(),
          ProductSearchPage(),
          CustomerPage(),
          OrdersPage()
        ].elementAt(index);
      },
    };
  }

  Widget _buildOffstageNavigator(int index) {
    var routeBuilders = _routeBuilders(context, index);

    return Offstage(
      offstage: _selectedIndex != index,
      child: Navigator(
        key: _navigatorKeys[index],
        onGenerateRoute: (routeSettings) {
          return MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => routeBuilders[routeSettings.name]!(context),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have used an offstage widget which will just remove the ui from the stage. It wont reload when the index is changed. You have to create a list

```dart
List screens = [
HomePage(),
          ProductSearchPage(),
          CustomerPage(),
          OrdersPage()
],
//Then in body use
body: screens[index]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the api call in on Tap because all the pages will be initialized at a time that's why you are facing this issue.

Just check the condition on Tap for a currently selected index and write down the API call there.